# Sql Server Restoring Process Time Takes Too Long Time

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, restore

I have 7 databases on my reporting server. I restore those databases every night with differetial backups. Normally, the differential restore time was taking about 1 or 1.5 hour for each databases. Last day, my restore process took so much long time. 4 of those databases has restored about 11 hours. The other one was completed normally. What can cause those databases to take such a long restoring time?

Comment: Is [IFI](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/instant-file-initialization/) enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. @DenisRubashkin

Comment: You might find some interesting information in [Babysitting a Slow Backup or Restore](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-66-babysitting-a-slow-backup-or-restore)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @ScottHodgin

Comment: Are you dropping the databases before you restore them or are you using the [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#REPLACEoption) keyword in your [`RESTORE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command?

Comment: Are the backups close to the same size? If not, its possible that compression on the backups was turned off. That can increase IO time from network/disk.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener Yes, i use replace keyword in my restore command. In fact, I restore my database from my full backup with replace keyword. After restoring , i restore the same database Daily differential backups. This process repeats itself every week like this.

Comment: @alexander7567 No, backup compression is on. There was no problem 3 days ago. Suddenly this problem occured.

Answer (score 2):

1. The Log file of database is fragmented too much and there are too many Virtual Log Files. This would force recovery to take longer time. Run dbcc loginfo(db_name) on database and tell me how many rows it returns. Please see [How a Log file Can affect database restore time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/05/21/how-a-log-file-structure-can-affect-database-recovery-time/)
2. The SQL Server service account does not have "[Perform Volume Maintenance Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx)" privilege or what you call as Instant File Initialization is enabled or not. If not the restore time can significantly increase
3. I suggest  you have a look at [Optimizing Backup and Restore Performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190954%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SQL Server

Comment: First Db has 2654 rows. 2. has 1870 rows. 3. has 312 rows. 4. has 35715 rows. 5 has 76 rows. Instant File Initialization is enabled. I checked it once again. @benedikt

Comment: reduce the number of VLs using the steps from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/05/21/how-a-log-file-structure-can-affect-database-recovery-time/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you state that you did restore before and it took much less time I would quess that some of the following could be the reason:

- some other process on the reporting server taking a lot of resources (in- and outside of `SQL Server`), that put high load on disks;
- slow network connection between backups and reporting server if backups are located on a network share;
- some process loading the disks with backups preventing fast reading of them by `SQL Server`.